# Sorting a vector based on multiple value types

Tags: c++

I'm looking to sort a custom struct based on multiple values... I've handled instances where I had to sort by 2 different numbers just fine using < > in a custom sort method... except this time I have to sort by 2 booleans and a number.

```
struct MyStruct
{
B1 = false;
B2 = true;
N1 = 0;
}
```

Now... I want it to sort as the following...

Anything that has B1 and B2 true comes first.
Anything that has B1 comes next.

Those 2 sections need to also be sorted by N1 (lower = comes first)

So B1 and B2's need to be ordered N1 lowest to highest.
Followed by just B1's ordered N1 lowest to highest.
Followed by everything else ordered lowest to highest.

Here's my attempt so far...

```
    if (lhs.boss && lhs.isLOS && lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
        return true;
    if (lhs.boss && lhs.isLOS && lhs.distancetome > rhs.distancetome)
        return false;
    if (lhs.boss && lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
        return true;
    if (lhs.boss && lhs.distancetome > rhs.distancetome)
        return false;
    if (lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
        return true;

    return false;
```

Comment: What's the problem? This is still just a simple lexicographic order...

Comment: My mind isn't working right I guess...I mean... should I just do

if B1 && B2 and N1 < N2 return true
if B1 and N1 < N2 return true
if N1 < N2 return true
return false

Comment: `  if (lhs.boss && lhs.isLOS && lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
   return true;
  if (lhs.boss && lhs.isLOS && lhs.distancetome > rhs.distancetome)
   return false;
  if (lhs.boss && lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
   return true;
  if (lhs.boss && lhs.distancetome > rhs.distancetome)
   return false;
  if (lhs.distancetome < rhs.distancetome)
   return true;

  return false;`

Comment: Can you paste the entire functor method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
struct complex_comparison
{
    bool operator()(const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.B1 && lhs.B2 != rhs.B1 && rhs.B2 ? lhs.B1 && lhs.B2 > rhs.B1 && rhs.B2 :
                                   lhs.B1 != rhs.B1 ? lhs.B1 > rhs.B1 :
                                   lhs.N1 < rhs.N1;
    }
};
```

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4888ac34d2ca6bb